# Es correcto decir "estas disciplinas comparten un mismo objeto de estudio pero no un mismo objetivo de estudio"

Tags: sinónimos

Estoy haciendo una trabajo escrito, en una parte hablo sobre diferentes disciplinas provenientes de otras como la medicina, la psicología o la biología, que tienen en común que estudian al sistema nervioso o la conducta. Pues, quiero señalar que aún a pesar de eso sus objetivos y sus razones para estudiar sobre estos temas difieren.
Pero no sé si resulta redudante, o si tiene sentido plantearlo con esa oración.

Answer (score 2):

Si buscamos en DRAE, encontramos que ["objeto"](https://dle.rae.es/objeto) significa, entre otras cosas, lo siguiente:

> 1. m. Todo lo que puede ser materia de conocimiento o sensibilidad de parte del sujeto, incluso este mismo.
> 2. m. Aquello que sirve de materia o asunto al ejercicio de las facultades mentales.
> 3. m. Término o fin de los actos de las potencias.
> 4. m. Fin o intento a que se dirige o encamina una acción u operación.
> 5. m. Materia o asunto de que se ocupa una ciencia o estudio.

mientras que "objetivo" remite al significado (4) de "objeto".

No me parece que "objeto de estudio" y "objetivo de estudio" se solapen porque, cuando "objeto" significa "objetivo", normalmente definimos el sustantivo que sigue: *objeto **del** estudio*. Cuando decimos "objeto de estudio", la acepción suele ser diferente de (4).

Dicho esto, decir: "Estas disciplinas comparten un mismo objeto de estudio pero no un mismo objetivo de estudio" me parece correcto, obviando por supuesto la repetición de "de estudio". Sugiero: *Estas disciplinas comparten el mismo objeto de estudio pero no el mismo objetivo.*

Comment: Muchísimas gracias, esta respuesta me es de mucha ayuda ;)

Answer (score 0):

Si bien no hay una definición de *objeto de estudio* en el diccionario de la RAE, de lo que sí estoy seguro, en base a mi propia experiencia y a lo que se puede encontrar en la mayoría de sitios ([como este](https://www.ejemplos.co/objeto-de-estudio/)), es que *objeto de estudio* es en algún sentido sinónimo de *objetivo de estudio*.

Pero igualmente **no te recomiendo usar la expresión "*objetivo de estudio de* + < una disciplina >"**. No suena tan bien y difícilmente la vayás a encontrar. **Es mejor "*objeto de estudio de* + < una disciplina >"**. La razón de esto es que *objeto* tiene connotaciones de un fin último (quizá inalcanzable) mientras que el *objetivo* se suele entender como un sub-fin que contribuye a la realización del *objeto*. Ejemplos de situaciones en donde *objetivo* suene mejor serían:

- El objetivo de una práctica de laboratorio
- Los objetivos de un programa de investigación
- Los objetivos de una determinada acción concreta

Ahora voy directo a tu pregunta. No tiene sentido que el objeto de estudio de alguna disciplina como las que mencionaste sea el 'sistema nervioso' o 'la conducta', porque es algo demasiado amplio como para circunscribirlo al ámbito médico—menos hoy, que los campos están cada vez más fragmentados. La antropología, la filosofía, la sociología e incluso la estadística también podrían ser disciplinas que en algún sentido estén interesadas en estudiar 'el sistema nervioso' o 'la conducta'. Presupuse que te referías en específico al ámbito médico. En este caso—y probablemente en cualquier otro—lo más apropiado sería algo como:

> Podemos reconocer que tanto la medicina, la psicología o la biología estudian en algún sentido al sistema nervioso o a la conducta. Pero sus objetos de estudio son bien diferentes.

Si te fijás bien, incluso a su vez en cada una de esas tres disciplinas se pueden reconocer 'sub-disciplinas', cada una con su propio objeto de estudio. Estas últimas no necesariamente están dispuestas 'en armonía' ni reconociéndose como sub-disciplinas de una disciplina más abarcativa, ya que muchas veces se habla de 'corrientes' que surgen como una crítica al paradigma que actualmente ha estado vigente al interior de la disciplina. Pero para hablar sobre eso ya lo tenemos a Kuhn. Saludos.

Comment: Gracias! también tomaré tu sugerencia y la agregaré a mi trabajo : )